# VBA PivotTable Type mismatch error cross workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

Here is a snippet of the code that is giving me trouble, I cant figure out a solution, because it works for a smaller range and then runs into Run-time error '13': Type mismatch when I increase the range to its actually size

```
Set dataRange = wbData.Sheets("RawData").Range(Cells(1, "A"), Cells(endCell, "AA"))
'create root cause pivot chart
wbReviewPivots.Sheets("RootCausesCleaned").Activate
Set rcPTCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=dataRange)
Set rcPT = ActiveSheet.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=rcPTCache, TableDestination:=Range("A1"))
    With rcPT
        .PivotFields("Root Cause").Orientation = xlRowField
        .PivotFields("Root Cause (Sub Category)").Orientation = xlRowField
        .PivotFields("Remedy Task ID").Orientation = xlDataField
    End With
```

The problem occurs on line 4 creating the cache, I have heard unexpected errors can be run into when passing a Range. Is there a easy way to fix this or do I need to configure my range as a String?

Comment: Its a pivot cache everything is defined elsewhere in the code, the error only occurs when i make the data range much larger

Comment: tested that no effect, I have cut the problem down to a certain column within my excel data worksheet. The column  contains a very long string ~200 chars per cell. the code runs perfectly fine if I exclude it from the range. I dont need to include it but there is crucial data on either side of it. Is there a way to exclude the data from the cache without moving the two segments elsewhere and creating a cache from that.